# How to open the second form after the first form when creating slack workflow using Deno SDK

Tags: slack-api, deno

I am creating a slack workflow with deno sdk. I am new in this deno sdk but trying hard to solve the problem since yesterday. Please help.

The documentation says (https://api.slack.com/reference/functions/open_form)
When creating a workflow that will have a step to open a form, your workflow must have the call to OpenForm be its first step or ensure the preceding step is interactive. An interactive step will generate a fresh pointer to use for opening the form.

My workflow code is as follows

```
import { DefineWorkflow, Schema } from "deno-slack-sdk/mod.ts";
import { submitIssue_function } from "../functions/submit_issue_function.ts";

export const submitIssueWorkflow = DefineWorkflow({
  callback_id: "submit_issue",
  title: "Workflow for submitting issue",
  input_parameters: {
    properties: {
      interactivity: {
        type: Schema.slack.types.interactivity,
      },
    },
    required: ["interactivity"],
  },
});

const inputForm = submitIssueWorkflow.addStep(
  Schema.slack.functions.OpenForm,
  {
    title: "Submit the issue",
    interactivity: submitIssueWorkflow.inputs.interactivity,
    submit_label: "Submit the issue",
    fields: {
      elements: [
        {
          name: "message",
          title: "Your question",
          type: Schema.slack.types.rich_text,
        },
      ],
      required: ["message"],
    },
  },
);



const chooseChannelForm = submitIssueWorkflow.addStep(
  Schema.slack.functions.OpenForm,
  {
    title: "Choose the channel",
    interactivity: submitIssueWorkflow.inputs.interactivity,
    submit_label: "Submit",
    fields: {
      elements: [
        {
          name: "channel",
          title: "Mention the channel name", //actually will use a dropdown of channel names here but let's not worry about this input
          type: Schema.slack.types.rich_text,
        },
      ],
      required: ["channel"],
    },
  },
);
```

How to ensure the preceding step (first form) is interactive. An interactive step will generate a fresh pointer to use for opening the second form.

Comment: can you try to replace `chooseChannelForm` interactivity input?
change it to this:

`interactivity: inputForm.outputs.interactivity,`